# Sorting query ASC giving wrong order

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a simple Query that should query through a meta value containing a number. 1 should be first, 2 should be 2nd and 3 should be 3rd.

For some reason, it comes out like 1, 3, 2 in my query. What am I missing??

```
$args = array(
      'post_type'      => 'x-portfolio',
      'posts_per_page' => $count,
      'paged'          => $paged,
      'orderBy'        => 'meta_value_num',
      'meta_key'       => 'liste_nr',
      'order'          => 'asc',
      'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => $filters,
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
          'field'    => 'name',
          'terms'    => 'Accessories',
          'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
      )
    );
```

Comment: Try this 'order'  => 'ASC'

Comment: @Dipak Dholakiya unfortunately that didn't do any difference.

Comment: Try with meta query

Comment: The only logical explanation that would make sense, with the info we have so far, is that your meta data is not actually what you think it is. Please _verify_ what is actually stored for those posts, directly on the database level.

Comment: I am not sure why SO still holds a tag for wordpress, but could you _also_ ask on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this before when a CPT, plugin etc has done a custom query and they never reset and it can completely override yours.

Try dropping wp_reset_query() before it and make sure you are using it after.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/